# Macbook Pro 2011 Heat Problems

Tags: hardware, temperature

This is more a general enquiry into whether I should be concerned, but I have a 2011 Macbook Pro 13" and over the last week and a half I have noticed the left side of the case (power point, QWE keys down to wrist rest) is getting uncomfortably hot during normal operations. I listen to Spotify and work on Google Docs / Transmit / Textmate with 1password in the background, but that's about it.

I installed iStat Pro to see if I could see anything wrong, and I'm seeing the following numbers: 
CPU: 64 deg,
Enclosure 1: 35deg
Enclosure 2: 35deg
Enclosure 3: 37deg

and the fan is running at 2000rpm. Is this cause for concern / something I should take into Apple for investigation? I can imagine it being difficult to reproduce because it requires about an hour and a half of use before it starts to heat up noticeably.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Open the computer (have a look at Youtube for instructions) and blow away all dust that has gathered. I use compressed air you can buy in a hardware store for this. If you haven't done it on a computer that is a couple of years old it can make a huge difference.

Good to do it before the summer (if you are located on the northern hemisphere). The problem is that the more the fan blows, the more dust it suck into the computer which makes the fan go even faster etc.